# Centering visual studio 2015's designer screen

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, centering

I've been searching in the options but cant seem to find it.
Is it possible to center the designer screen of visual studio?
Just centering in visual studio, this has nothing to do with the application I am creating.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option to do so, cheat a little and pin the toolbox and re-size the width of the properties, and push the form to the center of the screen.[image]